# TYPO3 v7.6.x migration to Drupal 8

Tags: migration, typo3, database-migration, drupal-8, typo3-7.6.x

I have to migrate a complex TYPO3 v7.6.30 website to Drupal 8.
So far I have investigated how TYPO3's administration part works.
I've also been digging into the TYPO3 database to find the correct mapping pattern, but I just don't seem to be getting anywhere.

My question is if there is a nice way to map/join all of the content with it's images/files/categories, so I can get row by row all page content like:

- title
- description
- text fields
- images
- documents
- tables
- ...

So in the end I will end up with a joined table with all of the data for each page on a single row, which then I can map in the migration.

I need a smooth way to map the pages with their fields.
I need the same for users (haven't researched this one yet).
The same is for the nesting of the pages in order to recreate the menus in the new CMS.

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need a detailed plan of the configuration and then much understanding how TYPO3 works.
Here a basic introduction:

All content is organized in records and the main table is `pages`, the pagetree.
For nearly all records you have some common fields:

- `uid` unique identifier
- `pid` page ID (in which 'page' is the record 'stored', important for editing) (even `pages` are stored in `pages` to build a page tree)
- `title` name of record
- `hidden`, `deleted`,`starttime`,`endtime`, `fe_group` for visibility

there are fields for

- versioning and workspaces
- language support
- sorting

some records (especially `tt_content`) have type fields, which decide how the record and which fields of it are used
there are relations to files (which are represented by `sys_file` records, and other records like file metadata or categories).

Aside from the default content elments where the data is stored in the `tt_content` record itself you can have plugins which display other records, (e.g. news, addresses, events, ...) or which get their data from another application or server.

You need to understand the complete configuration to save all.

---

What you might need is a special rendering of the pages.
That is doable with TYPO3: aside from the default HTML-rendering you can define other page types where you can get the content in any kind you define. e.g. xml, json, CSV, ...

This needs detailed knowledge of the individual TYPO3 configuration. So nobody can give you a full detailed picture of your installation.
And of course you need a good knowledge of your drupal target installation to answer the question 'what information should be stored where?'